# passing QC ota api connection object between different sub's in VB macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send Qcconnection object between different sub's in excel macro.Please help in finding the syntax to send the connection object.here is a sample code for the question i am asking
sub defecttracker()

code to get username,pwd,project,domain
qcconnection set here

sub defectfilter()
...........
here i have a dim qcconnection.bugfactory

As the connection object will be unknown to the second sub defectfilter() I want to send the connection details to the second sub.Please give me solution to my problem.....

Comment: Pass the object as a parameter to the second sub.  Or use a global variable to hold the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a parameter to the new method:

```
Sub defectfilter(ByRef connection as Qcconnection)
     ...
End Sub
```